# How to modernize memalign in a C++ codebase?

Tags: c++, memory

I am modernizing/updating some old code that was originally written in C but is now used in a C++ codebase (no need to be backwards compatible). A bunch of this code is memory optimized with memalign with which I am very inexperienced with so my question is how one would update this code (or just leave it like it is) and whether there's even still any point to having it there at all:

The declaration:

```
float *table_pf;
```

And how it's initialized in the constructor:

```
table_pf = (float*)memalign(32, sizeof(float) * TALBLE_SIZE);
```

I was unable to find any equivalent for modern C++ but I may also have just missed it. Usually I would simply convert the pointer to a std::vector or std::array but this does not work when using memalign.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by rewriting this code? C++17 has [`aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) but that is just the standardized version of `memalign` so you should probably explain the goal you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `std::array` is an option for you, it's easy to align (same applies to bare arrays):

```
alignas(32) std::array<TALBLE_SIZE, float> table;
```

The standard function for dynamically allocating over-aligned memory inherited from C is `std::aligned_alloc`. It's nearly identical to the non-standard `memalign`; only difference is that it's stricter in requiring the size to be a multiple of the alignment. A pure C++ option is to use the operator new with `std::align_val_t` operand which will by default use `std::aligned_alloc`.

It's not a good idea to use the bare pointer returned by the allocation function though: You should use RAII. One option is to use `std::vector` with an allocator that uses over-aligned allocation function. Standard library doesn't provide such allocator though, so a custom one needs to be used. A more straightforward but less flexible option is to use `std::unique_ptr` with a deleter that calls `std::free` (or operator delete in case you had used operator new).

Answer (score 0):

The code returns a `TABLE_SIZE` array of floats, the address would be aligned to 32 bytes.
`malloc` would have used the default alignment, which normally means `double` size alignment (but can be larger, implementation dependent).
For an array of floats - normal allocation and alignment is sufficient.
You would use `memalign` or the c++ `aligned_alloc` or `posix_memalign` to return a non regular alignment.
For instance, when using SSE or other SIMD extensions, that may require larger memory alignment than the default one.
My advice is to read the code, see if memory alignment is indeed needed, and either lose it for a normal allocation or move to `std::aligned_alloc` if it is really required.
The use of the literal `32` is suspicious in my opinion.